# iOS: How to obtain ZipKit without using Mercurial?

Tags: ios, mercurial, zip

I installed Mercurial, but true to its name it is failing to run when I try to download ZipKit.
I get this message:

```
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in ....     
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload 
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode]
(check your install and PYTHONPATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Mercurial can only be run from the account under which it was installed, at least on OS/X. Therefore I merely had to switch bad to my main account and fetch zipkit.